# Having trouble with the gcc -I flag

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glfw

I'm sure this is something embarrassingly simple but I can't get gcc or clang to use a custom include directory.
I'm using Linux Mint. The project lives in a directory called `morg`.

This is the mind blowing code I have at `morg/src/main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

int main(){
    printf("hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The directory `morg/include` contains `GLFW/glfw3.h`
The directory `morg/lib` contains `libglfw3.a`, the compiled library I'm trying to use.

I have a bash file at `morg/build.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -v -g -o -Iinclude -Llib -lglfw3 morg src/main.c
```

I used [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html) website to help me put it together.
The compiler is able to see the static library I am trying to link to but running the above results in the following:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-Wextra' '-v' '-g' '-o' '-Iinclude' '-Llib' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu src/main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase main -g -Wall -Wextra -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat-security -o /tmp/cc7OGbRB.s
GNU C11 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) version 7.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 7.4.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C11 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) version 7.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 7.4.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: fa57db1fe2d756b22d454aa8428fd3bd
src/main.c:2:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I can see `include "..." starts here` is empty and `include <...> starts here` is unchanged whether or not I include `-Iinclude` in the command line options.

I am also a tiny bit concerned about the lines that say `ignoring nonexistent directory` but it doesn't look like it's related.

I thought clang might provide more a more helpful error message but it's basically identical.

For what it's worth I've used GLFW before but on Windows with Visual Studio.

What am I missing? I have scoured the internet high and low in my search and am feeling pretty dumb.

**Edit:**
As the top comment says I had the `-o` command in the wrong place but that wasn't the only problem! I needed to put `-lglfw` (not `-lglfw3`) after the main source file like so:

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -Iinclude -Llib -o morg src/main.c -lglfw`

Answer (score 2):

Look like the -o option is misplaced, causing the error.

try this

gcc -Wall -Wextra -v -g -Iinclude -Llib -lglfw3 -o morg src/main.c

Comment: I...thank you. Wow. Thank you. You're a wonderful human being. I feel pretty dumb but you know what? I'm not going to forget. I wish you the best of health and safety.

Comment: with `gcc` and `ld`  nothing will be 'pulled in' from the libraries unless there is a unresolved external reference that the library might be able to resolve.  Therefore, the source file: `src/main.c` must be listed before the libraries